# Where do I submit an ACH file in my application code?

Tags: money-transfer, checking-account, ach

i have 2 bank accounts Gobank and TD bank.

i need to Debit Gobank and Credit TD bank via **ACH**.

okay i understand the part where i collect information for each bank but where do i submit the information?
i know that i can simply link 1 bank to the other and transfer but i would miss what really happens and how it happened.

i found some software on *github* that is supposed to do `ACH` transactions but i haven't tested it yet.
i am trying to understand direct deposits here.

**My Questions**

Where do i Submit the ACH file, to URL or somewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You, presumably an individual and not a bank, financial institution, or business that needs to process payments, will not have direct access to the ACH (Automated Clearing House) network of the banking system.

Usually individuals will initiate an ACH request indirectly via their bank that holds the money you want to transfer, in this case Gobank.  If your account has "bill pay" setup you should be able to request a payment to TD Bank there.  Otherwise you will need to contact a representative from Gobank and ask them how you follow their procedures to perform an ACH transfer to TD Bank.

It's also possible to initiate an ACH transfer at the receiving bank, TD Bank, and to do that you'll need to contact TD and follow their procedure for performing the transfer.